# How to convert from string to array with angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to delete a row from my database table using php and angular. I'm using "Splice" but my data is a string and I need to convert to an array. can someone please help?

This is my code:

controller:

```
  $scope.delete = function(deletingId, $index) {
        var params = $.param({"customer_id":deletingId});
        $http({
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          url: 'http://localhost:8081/hamatkin/api/delete-customer.php/',
          method: "GET",
          data: params
        }).success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          var arr=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
          $scope.customerDetails = arr;
          $scope.customerDetails.splice($index, 1);
```

The error I'm getting :

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: $scope.customerDetails.splice is not a function
```

delete-customer.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

  include_once 'Customer.php';
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_results = utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$customer = new Customer();


if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
   $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];
   $del = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE customer_id='".$customer_id."'";
   mysql_query($connect, $del);
 }


$newURL = "/hamatkin/#/customerCards";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>
```

html

```
  <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in customers | filter:search_query | orderBy: order_query:reverse_query">
            <!-- <td>{{$index + 1}}</td> -->
            <td>{{ x.customer_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.kind_Of_Customer}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.full_name}}</td>
            <td><a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCardDetails/{{ x.customer_id}}"  class="btn btn-primary btn- active">הצג פרטי לקוח </a></td>
            <td><a ng-click="delete(x.customer_id, $index)" class="btn btn-primary btn- active">מחיקה</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

console.log(data)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Styles -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib\bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" />

        <!-- Liberaries -->
        <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="lib/angular.js"></script> -->
        <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link href="scripts\bootstrap.min.js" />

        <!-- Application Model, Direectives, Services & Controllers -->
        <script src="scripts/App.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script> -->

        <!-- controllers-->
        <script src="Controllers/loginCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/customerFormCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/customerCardsCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/stockCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/bodyCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/ordersCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/reportsCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/recordExpensesCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/supplierListCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/supplierFormCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="Controllers/customerCardDetailsCtrl.js"></script>


        <title>מערכת מידע רומן המתקין</title>
    </head>


    <body ng-app="dataSystem" ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
        <!--Navigation Bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ng-hide="isNavTabsHidden()">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
                    <img class="img-rounded" src="images/black logo.jpg" style="width:155px" />
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/hamatkin/#/reports">דוחות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/hamatkin/#/recordExpenses">הכנסות והוצאות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/hamatkin/#/stock">ניהול מלאי וספקים</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/hamatkin/#/orders">ניהול הזמנות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/hamatkin/#/customerForm">ניהול לקוחות</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="/hamatkin/#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> התנתק</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> ניהול הרשאות</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <br /><br /><br />


        <!--טאב ניהול לקוחות-->
        <div class="containers-wrapper">
            <div class="container" ng-hide="costumerHidden()">

                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerForm" class="list-group-item">טופס רישום לקוח</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCards" class="list-group-item">כרטיסי לקוחות</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">רשימת פניות מלקוחות</a>
                    </div>

            </div>

        <!--טאב ניהול מלאי וספקים-->
            <div class="container" ng-hide="stockHidden()">

                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">טופס רישום מלאי</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">טופס עריכת/מחיקת מלאי</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">רשימת מלאים למכירה</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">רשימת ציוד עבודה</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">בדיקת זמינות מלאי</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/supplierForm" class="list-group-item">טופס רישום ספק</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/supplierList" class="list-group-item">רשימת ספקים</a>
                    </div>

            </div>

        <!--טאב ניהול הזמנות-->

            <div class="container" ng-hide="ordersHidden()">

                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">טופס הזמנה חדשה</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">רשימת הזמנות</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">טופס הצעת מחיר</a>
                        <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">הצעות מחיר בהמתנה</a>
                    </div>

            </div>



        <!--טאב דוחות-->
        <div class="container" ng-hide="reportsHidden()">


                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">דו"ח מלאים לפי סוגים</a>
                    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">דו"ח הצעות מחיר</a>
                    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">דו"ח מכירות על פי סוגי מלאי</a>
                    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">דו"ח הוצאות לספקים</a>
                    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">דו"ח הוצאות לפי חודשים</a>
                    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">דו"ח הכנסות לפי חודשים</a>
                    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">דו"ח לקוחות חדשים חודשי</a>
                </div>


        </div>

        <!--טאב הכנסות והוצאות-->
        <div class="container" ng-hide="isIncome_expensesHidden()">
          <div class="list-group">
              <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">טופס תיעוד הוצאה</a>
              <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">טופס תיעוד הכנסה</a>
              <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/" class="list-group-item">רשימת הוצאות</a>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!--left side screen-->
        <div class="view-content left-side-screen">
          <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
      </div>

        <!--Footer-->
        <div class="footer" ng-hide="isFooterHidden()">

            <p>Copyright @ 2016 Denis & Denis. All Rights Reserved</p>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: $scope.customerDetails.splice($index, 1); what is $index here ?

Comment: @tanyaa What you get `arr` post the console log resul

Comment: @tanyaa, `JSON.parse` will turn a json into an object, not an array.

Comment: @AranS ok, what should I do?

Comment: First you need to add more information: You get a string from an `$http` call. Then you want it to be an array. Is it an array of words? characters? does the index represents the word index? please elaborate.

Comment: @AranS I have a php file "delete-customer.php" and it returns a string. to use the Splice function I need to convert it to an array

Answer (score 0):

Hi u have to first find the index which one u wants to splice then u have to splice , **SPlice is for Array Items check whether the Item is array first**  for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/Nzz4T4AmkLmcr7frxyH1?p=preview

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arrylist = [{
        "id": 53,
        "name": "abced"

    }, {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "gayu"

    }]

    $scope.doc = {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "abced"

    }
    console.log($scope.arrylist)

    var index = $scope.arrylist.findIndex(function(item) {
        if (item.id == $scope.doc.id) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (index !== -1) {
        //Removing the test from list;
        $scope.arrylist.splice(index, 1);
    }

    console.log($scope.arrylist)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON.parse` will turn JSON into JS object. In your scenario, you are invoking a `splice` function which exists on Array prototype, whereas your `arr` variable is in fact a plain string object which has no such function.

Assuming your string is formatted in some way, let's say - customer names are seperated by a comma, you can use `split` function. This will turn your string into an array of seperated elements devided by the required format.

Like this:

```
var clientsToDelete = arr.split(","); // comma splitting
clientsToDelete.splice($index, 1);
```

Comment: thanks! the error is gone, but it still doesn't delete. no errors now. I have -              .success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          var arr=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
          $scope.customerDetails = arr;
          var arr2 = arr.split(",");
          arr2.splice($index, 1);

Comment: You are deleting an element from `arr2`, but `$scope.customerDetails` is not affected by this change.

Comment: Are you using `$scope.customerDetails` in your template? if so in what way? `ng-repeat` perhaps?

Comment: you mean this? <tr ng-repeat="x in customers">
            <!-- <td>{{$index + 1}}</td> -->
            <td>{{ x.customer_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.kind_Of_Customer}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.full_name}}</td>
            <td> {{ x.id}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.city}} </td>
            <td><a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCardDetails/{{ x.customer_id}}"  class="btn btn-primary btn- active">הצג פרטי לקוח </a></td>
            <td><a ng-click="delete(x.customer_id, $index)" class="btn btn-primary btn- active">מחיקה</td>

Comment: I think it will be hard to answer without seeing the big picture. Can you edit your question and include - controller, template, etc.

Comment: if you can please take a look

Comment: AranS? can you please take a look?

Comment: Maybe it's better we'll use Stack Overflow's chat, so I'll better understand the flow.

Comment: how can we use it? it says I don't have enough reputation...can you add me to chat?

Comment: let's try from here - you want to remove a customer from your `ng-repeat` list?

Comment: yes, yesterday I edited the question and put the php , controller and html code....it shows no errors

Comment: it show me all information about my index.html code don't know why...it doesn't show me nothing about the data itself

Comment: This is what you get in Chrome dev tools console? (if you're using Chrome)

Comment: This is really strange, it demands debugging the http call and investigate the request and the response headers.